# ActiveMerchant's PaypalExpressGateway purchase failing in sandbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

I'm having an issue with ActiveMerchant and Paypal Express that I have no idea how to debug.

My purchase method is returning false:

```
def purchase
  response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.purchase(1000, express_purchase_options)
  response.success?
end

def express_purchase_options
  {
    ip: ip,
    token: express_token,
    payer_id: express_payer_id
  }
end
```

Using `byebug` I can inspect the express_purchase_options and they are in fact being set. I have my Paypal sandbox accounts (business and personal) both set up.

**I'm following [this tutorial](http://jldbasa.github.io/blog/2014/01/25/rails-4-paypal-express-checkout-integration/).**

Comment: can you post the exact error message being returned?

Comment: There's no error message per se. `response.success?` just returns false. So I guess ActiveMerchant is working fine. It's just that my payment isn't being processed. I'm not really sure what I should check from this point on...

Comment: Normally I would use the API error code to troubleshoot the issue. without that I would verify my API credentials are correct (be sure you are not using your live credentials in the sandbox environment). You may want to reach out to the author of the posted instructions to see if he can help you troubleshoot the error.

Comment: That's sound advice. If I figure this out, I'll update. Thanks!

Comment: The project that required this problem to be solved was dropped, so I never figured it out. Sorry.